# Calling recursion with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, tree, permutation

I can't wrap my head around this:

```
def permut(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return [array]
    res = []
    for permutation in permut(array[1:]):
        for i in range(len(array)):
            res.append(permutation[:i] + array[0:1] + permutation[i:])
    return res
```

Particularly, the first line of the for loop - how would the tree look like? I can't come even close to having the same result as the function does from what I am drawing.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: The recursive call `permut(array[1:])` is operating from the second element of the array onward (i.e. the array minus the first element).

Comment: I want all the permutations of `[a, b, c, d, e]`.  I recursively find all the permutations of `[b,c,d,e]`, and for each of those, I stick `a` into each of five possible positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion "tree" is actually just a single path. There is just one place where a recursive call is made.

The algorithm is based on this idea:

If we know all permutations of the array that is one element shorter, then we can use those permutations to derive all the permutations of the current array: just add the excluded element at all possible positions in all those permutations.

The base case of your recursive function is when the array has just one element. In that case there is just one permutation, which is the array itself.

So lets run this code for input [1, 2, 3]:

The outer `for` loop makes a recursive call, passing it [2, 3] as argument.

- In this nested execution:

  The outer `for` loop makes a recursive call, passing it [3] as argument. We know that this is the base case, and so we get [[3]] as return value. Notice this is a list of lists.

  The outer `for` loop iterates twice, "injecting" 2 at index 0 and index 1 of [3], so that we get [2, 3] and [3, 2] as first results, and appended to `res`.

  `res` is returned to the caller, i.e. [[2, 3], [3, 2]]

The outer loop executes 3 times. Each time 1 is injected at a different position in each of the results of the recursive call. The first result of the recursive call is [2, 3]. Injecting 1 at the three possible positions, gives [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3] and [2, 3, 1], which are added to `res`. Then the second sublist that is in the recursive result is treated in the same way, and so we get [1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2]  and [3, 2, 1], which are also added to `res`.

Remark:

Your code identifies the base case as an array with one element. This is a shortcoming, because that means this function will run into a stack overflow error when you pass it an empty list.

Comment: That is a very nice and detailed explanation. Thank you!